# Objective C - Passing NSString to another view controller is returning null

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to pass an NSString ("theData") that contains the title of an annotation to another view controller, when I use NSLog in the first view controller it does return the correct title, however when I try displaying it in a text label in the next view controller it shows (null) and when I use NSLog in the second view controller it doesn't return anything either.

UbicacionVC.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.delegate = self;


 }


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
   {
    for (MKPointAnnotation *annotation in mapView.annotations) {
         if (view.annotation != annotation) {
        [mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        NSLog(@"yes!");

    }

}
NSString *theData = view.annotation.title;
DireccionVC *direccionVC = [[DireccionVC alloc] init];
direccionVC.theData = theData;


}
- (IBAction)Continue:(id)sender {
UIViewController *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DireccionVC"];
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:VC animated:YES];



 }
```

DireccionVC.h

```
 @interface DireccionVC : UIViewController{
     NSString *theData;

 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *theData;


 @end
```

DireccionVC.m

```
 @interface DireccionVC ()
 @end

 @implementation DireccionVC

 @synthesize theData;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.     
self.lblDireccion.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theData];

}
```

Comment: `DireccionVC *direccionVC = [[DireccionVC alloc] init];`: That's creating a whole new object. It's not the same object as `VC` that you used in `- (IBAction)Continue:(id)sender`. Not, any reason why using `retain`? Are you not using ARC? If yes, use `strong` instead.

Comment: I'm getting started with Objective C. How can I do it by not creating a whole new object? I can't use VC in that didSelectAnnotationView function and I can't use the Data in the Continue IBAction? And yes, you are right I changed retain for strong

Comment: Easy fix on top of my head. Change the line DireccionVC *direccionVC = [[DireccionVC alloc] init]; to DireccionVC *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DireccionVC"] as!  DireccionVC;

Comment: Keep it then? Add `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedData;` to `UbicacionVC.m`, and `_selectedData = view.annotation.title;`, then `VC.theData = _selectedData` on `Continue:`

Comment: @TheNitram Thank you for your help but that didn't work.

Comment: @Larme Thank you, when I add those changes I get an error in Continue "theData not found on object of type UIViewController"

Comment: `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DireccionVC"]` is a `DireccionVC` object, no? Then `DireccionVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DireccionVC"]; vc.theData = _selectedData; [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:vc animated:YES];`.

Comment: Also, please name your variables and methods starting with a lowercase (Continue: => continue, etc.)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Replace the

```
- (IBAction)Continue:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DireccionVC"];
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:VC animated:YES];
 }
```

With

```
- (IBAction)Continue:(id)sender {
    DireccionVC *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DireccionVC"] as! DireccionVC;
    VC.theData = theData;
    [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:VC animated:YES];
 }
```

Just make sure your DirectionVC in storyboard is in fact DirectionVC class. 
[image]